# Thinking sphinx results based on model preference

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thinking-sphinx

I have two models: 'A' and 'B', and want to search objects from both of them using Thinking sphinx, but I want all results of model 'A' first and then 'B'. How can I do that?
I pass the following options to sphinx query

```
{:match_mode=>:extended, :sort_mode=>:extended, :star=>true, :order=>"@relevance DESC", :ignore_errors=>true, :populate=>true, :per_page=>10, :retry_stale=>true, :classes => [A,B]}
```

And then get search results using:

```
ThinkingSphinx.search "*xy*", options
```

But it gives results in mixed ordering, whereas I need all 'A' objects first. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to add an attribute to both models' indices:

```
has "1", :as => :sort_order, :type => :integer
```

The number within the string should be different per model. And then your `:order` argument becomes:

```
:order => 'sort_order ASC, @relevance DESC'
```

Comment: this is a nice hack and would be useful in many places. For now, I used field-weights option to give more importance to 'A' model objects. Thanks.